# How to save the edited table in already existing csv file?

Tags: python

i was working on replacing the missing values and i did the mean for the table to replace the missing values, Now i couldn't update it on the csv file which i imported it at the first. Please help!

Comment: What did you use, pandas?

Comment: please provide a code and data sample to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Usually we write a new csv.